# What is this limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{1}{x} - 1)^x$?

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty }(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x=e$, but what if it is $\lim_{x \to \infty }( \frac{1}{x}-1)^x$?

Comment: What is the value of $\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^x$ for $x=2.5$?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limt+of+(1%2Fx-1)%5Ex+as+x+tends+to+infty

Comment: @MathLover Thank you!! I got it after your comment (and after plotting the function using desmos!)!

Comment: Something is wrong here.  As $x\to \infty$ the expression $\frac{1}{x}-1$ is negative, and it makes no sense to raise a negative value to a arbitrary positive real power $x$.  Please check the source of your Question and edit the statement as necessary.

Comment: @hardmath I got this question off of my university's test and I can assure you it's correct. And yeah you're right it doesn't make sense, I think the point of the question is to see that the limit does not exist. (And the answer was indeed that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not exist.  To see this, first pull out $-1$ from the base of the exponent

$$\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^x=(-1)^x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$

Now there is a common identity which you may already know of that states $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=e^a$$

Therefore, the factor of $\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ converges to $e^{-1}$, but $(-1)^x$ does not converge at all, and so the limit you gave does not exist.

To see why the identity holds, its easier to first see that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(1+ay\right)^{1/y}$ by setting $y=1/x$. Then,

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(1+ay\right)^{1/y} = L$$

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y}\log\left(1+ay\right) = \log L$$

Using L'Hopital's rule we see that

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log\left(1+ay\right)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{a/\left(1+ay\right)}{1}=a=\log L$$

Thus $L=e^a$.

Comment: Thank you rikhavshah! :D

Answer (score 2):

The limit does not exist if $x \in R$

because $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$ requirs $f(x)\ge 0$

if we apply this condition on our limit it becomes $$\frac{1}{x}-1 \ge 0$$
$$\frac{1}{x} \ge  1 $$
$$x \le  1 $$

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

The limit is in the form $(-1)^\infty$ which intuitively does not converge to a value or exist.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it so much simpler!